# Build problems with Maven and GeoTools (com.sun.javadoc)

Tags: java, maven, geotools

I'm trying to build GeoTools 8.0-RC2 (itself, not a tutorial project or the like) with Maven 3.0.4. When I run `mvn install` on the root pom it seems to work fine until a build error concerning `com.sun.javadoc` and `com.sun.tools.doclets` occurs.

The complete error trace is as follows:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project javadoc: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \GeoTools\GIT\build\maven\javadoc\src\main\java\org\geotools\maven\taglet\Source.java:[22,22] error: package com.sun.javadoc does not exist
[ERROR] \GeoTools\GIT\build\maven\javadoc\src\main\java\org\geotools\maven\taglet\Source.java:[23,28] error: package com.sun.tools.doclets does not exist
[ERROR] \GeoTools\GIT\build\maven\javadoc\src\main\java\org\geotools\maven\taglet\Source.java:[33,37] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \GeoTools\GIT\build\maven\javadoc\src\main\java\org\geotools\maven\taglet\Source.java:[40,50] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \GeoTools\GIT\build\maven\javadoc\src\main\java\org\geotools\maven\taglet\Source.java:[160,33] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \GeoTools\GIT\build\maven\javadoc\src\main\java\org\geotools\maven\taglet\Source.java:[171,33] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \GeoTools\GIT\build\maven\javadoc\src\main\java\org\geotools\maven\taglet\Tutorial.java:[20,22] error: package com.sun.javadoc does not exist
[ERROR] \GeoTools\GIT\build\maven\javadoc\src\main\java\org\geotools\maven\taglet\Tutorial.java:[21,28] error: package com.sun.tools.doclets does not exist
[ERROR] \GeoTools\GIT\build\maven\javadoc\src\main\java\org\geotools\maven\taglet\Tutorial.java:[32,39] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \GeoTools\GIT\build\maven\javadoc\src\main\java\org\geotools\maven\taglet\Tutorial.java:[38,49] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \GeoTools\GIT\build\maven\javadoc\src\main\java\org\geotools\maven\taglet\Tutorial.java:[130,33] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \GeoTools\GIT\build\maven\javadoc\src\main\java\org\geotools\maven\taglet\Tutorial.java:[141,33] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \GeoTools\GIT\build\maven\javadoc\src\main\java\org\geotools\maven\taglet\Source.java:[161,28] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \GeoTools\GIT\build\maven\javadoc\src\main\java\org\geotools\maven\taglet\Tutorial.java:[131,28] error: cannot find symbol
```

Unfortunately, I didn't find a solution with Google, but took a look at `lib\tools.jar` in my JDK 1.7.0 u5 and discovered the missing packages there. The pom that depends on `tools.jar` is `build\maven\javadoc\pom.xml`. There are two profiles, one for SUN JDKs and one for IBM JDKs:

```
<profile>
    <id>default-tools.jar</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>java.vendor</name>
            <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
  <!-- Note: a ${tools.jar} variable exists - we should try to use it. -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>
```

I'm on Windows 7 x64 and my `%JAVA_HOME%` is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05`. I tried messing around with it but had no luck. The error remains.
May `Sun Microsystems Inc.` be the problem because now it's from Oracle or `<version>1.5</version>` because I have version 1.7 installed?

Would be really nice if someone could help me out here!

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Can you try with either JDK 1.5 or change the pom to point the version to 1.7

Comment: I already tried changing `Sun Microsystems Inc.` to `Oracle`, `<version>1.5</version>` to `<version>1.7</version>` and `<systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>` to `<systemPath>${java.home}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>` in different combinations but still no luck.

Comment: This could be of help. Instead of just Oracle try Oracle Corporation. http://sunnytalkstech.blogspot.in/2011/08/maven-dependency-for-toolsjar-in-jdk7.html

Comment: Insane! This really worked! It seems GeoTools still doesn't officially support JDK 7. Many thanks for your hint! Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be of help. Instead of just Oracle try Oracle Corporation. 
http://sunnytalkstech.blogspot.in/2011/08/maven-dependency-for-toolsjar-in-jdk7.html

Comment: Addendum: The described solution is only a workaround to make it partly possible to build GeoTools with Oracle's JDK 7. Unfortunately, when you try to build the whole project (root pom) some dependencies fail to build because of compatibility problems with JDK 7. The officially supported JDK by GeoTools 8 (current development version) is JDK 6. So just install 1.6.0 u33, point your JAVA_HOME to it and the build works out of the box.